# jquery - how to not change background color of header row of dynamic table on hover

Tags: jquery, css

jquery - how do I **not** change the background color of **header** row of dynamic table on hover
I have a dynamic table that is being built with jquery and am using the .on

See [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/remy/sCGRL/) that shows the header row bg color does change on hover.

http://jsfiddle.net/remy/sCGRL/

```
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $(this).css("background-color", "lightgoldenrodyellow");
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $(this).css("background-color", "");
    }
}, "#PersonOrgTBL tr");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
}, "#PersonOrgTBL tr:not(:eq(0))");
```

You can also write it like:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave','#PersonOrgTBL tr:not(:eq(0))', function( e ){
    var color = e.type=='mouseenter' ? "lightgoldenrodyellow" : "";
    $(this).css({backgroundColor: color});
});
```

**[fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sCGRL/10/)**

Answer (score 1):

It is a condition do look here a practical example

```
if(!$(this).is(":first-child")) {
    $(this).css("background-color", "lightgoldenrodyellow");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sCGRL/12/

Comment: Thank you. It is good to see the different approaches and syntax used.